# Excel data sync fill down formulas every other

Tags: excel, data-connections

I have a data connection to a csv which fills out cells (A to N), I also have some basic formulas which run matches on that data (O to V).. the data I'm matching is grouped by every 2 rows.

If I import the data I can manually duplicate the formulas to appear like the image below.
[image]

If I select ***Fill down formulas in columns adjacent to data*** within the data connection properties, it will fill the forumals every row, not every second as seen below.
[image]

Comment: You could add something like `If(Mod(row(),2)=0,[your formula],"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a test to see if the row is even or not using `mod()`: `if(mod(row(),2)=0,[your formula],"")`